# Java Logger Object not appending to log file

Tags: java, logging

I have the following code;

```
_fileHandler = new FileHandler(_logFileNameAndpath, true);
_logger = Logger.getLogger("MyLogger");
_logger.addHandler(_fileHandler);
SimpleFormatter formatter = new SimpleFormatter();
_fileHandler.setFormatter(formatter);
_logger.log(Level.INFO, message);
```

However, the logging, to me at least, looks weird in that it creates something like 100 files all named with a numeric extension such at .75, .76, .77 etc.

Can anyone shed any light as to how to make the logger append to the specified file?

Comment: Why aren't you log4j.properties or log4j.xml?

Comment: @CoolBeans - This is java.util.logging, not log4j.

Comment: Aahh, I have not used that in forever. So absolutely forgot about it. Thanks Andy!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
_fileHandler = new FileHandler(_logFileNameAndpath, true, 1 );
```

The last argument is:

```
count - the number of files to use
```

Incidentally, you can also configure logging through a file sometimes named ''logging.properties,'' specified through the property `java.util.logging.config.file`. You can find a sample logging.properties file, with instructions, in your JRE directory tree.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to put everything in a StringBuffer and then finally log it at each class or package.